# Two status bars at iPhone app startup

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uistatusbar, uilaunchimagefile

This makes no sense, but suddenly one of the iPhone (iOS 5.0 target) apps I'm developing **starts up with two (2) statusbars**! Furthermore it's not always, only with some installs with some people.

This is the only related question I could find: [Why do I see double status bars when starting my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758376/why-do-i-see-double-status-bars-when-starting-my-app)

App has **three default.png files**, all created by opening iPhone simulator and taking a screenshot. The files were drag & dropped into project target "Launch Images" section. No yellow warning triangles, so everything should be ok:

```
Default.png           320 x 480  (iPhone simulator)
Default@2x.png        640 x 960  (iPhone Retina 3.5-inch simulator)
Default-568h@2x.png   640 x 1136 (iPhone Retina 4.0-inch simulator)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) seem to say this setup is correct - but now even I started to see 2 statusbars at startup!

**Update:**

Getting crazier! I edited first two files - and **saved without edits** as-is. Problem fixed. Same with third image - problem remains !!! **iPhone Retina 4-inch simulator was started using 3.5-inch launch image** !!!

Yep, I labelled the pics. With different numbers.

So first two cases might have been some image file format issues and the third case looks like Apple defect. Any other guesses?

Xcode project target summary has **Default-568h@2x.png** image in box, it's the real image with correct number, and there is no yellow warning sign. That file does exists in file system, is in same folder as the two other ones and is included in "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. What else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this would be happening irregularly, but I think I have an idea. When you said that you took your screenshots with the iOS simulator, the status bar may have been saved as part of the image. Then, iOS is showing your Default.png squished down by 20px creating the illusion of two status bars during launch.

Comment: Image sizes are as documented by Apple, but I'll try cutting the image statusbars away